# Android :error with tabhost

Tags: android

Hi i'm doing something with android but i have an error 
i have  2 xml files whom are included in the file activity_main.xml in order to to be used in a tabhost

pps.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/pps" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="#fff"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ppc"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"   />
-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
    android:text="label" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/field"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
    android:singleLine="false" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/field"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="@string/nomcheck" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/groupradio"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/check"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/radio3" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/valider"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@id/groupradio"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Valider" 
 >
</Button>    

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@id/valider"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

others.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/others" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="#fff"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/texte"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TabHost
  android:id="@+id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

  <TabWidget
      android:id="@+id/tabwidget"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
  <FrameLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <include layout="@layout/pps"/>  

      <include layout="@layout/others" />

    </FrameLayout>


</TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the Main-Activity.java

```
package com.example.useonglet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.pps);
    spec.setIndicator("PPS");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.others);
    spec.setIndicator("AUTRES");
    tabs.addTab(spec);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

and the error is :
your tabhost must have a tabwidget whose id attribute is 'android.r.id.tabs'

Comment: yes i have done it but always the same error

Comment: I don't use tab hosts but that is the same kind of error with a `ListActivity` where you need to have a `ListView` with an `id` of `@android:id/list`. Have you tried giving your `TabWidget` an `id` of `"@android:id/tabs"`?

Comment: @codeMagic it seem it is the solution because the error is not shown but let me correct the rest after i will post a message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says

```
your tabhost must have a tabwidget whose id attribute is 'android.r.id.tabs'
```

In your xml, give your `TabWidget` this `id`.

```
<TabWidget
  android:id="@android:id/tabs"   <-- Here
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```